# JPA Join Query using @Query in repository

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables with composite primary keys and also it has foreign key relation ship. I am trying `JPA` mappings between these tables. We need to get the below join query result from JPA repository

```
select * from A i inner join B n on i.id = n.id where i.id = 'XXX' and i.version=99999;
```

**Table: A fields are**

id, name, version are primary keys

**Table: B fields are**

id, name, version, type are primary keys id, name, version, are foreign keys

```
@Table(name = "A")
@IdClass(APK.class)
public class A {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Version")
    private String version;

    //getter setter, toString, equals and hash code

    @OneToOne @JoinColumn(name="ID")
    private B b;
    getter setter

}

public class APK implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private Long version;
    private String name;

    //getter setter, toString, equals and hash code

}

@Table(name = "B")
@IdClass(BPK.class)
public class B {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Version")
    private String version;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "TYPE")
    private Type type;

    // getter setter, toString, equals and hash code

    @OneToOne @MapsId("ID")
    private A a;

    //getter setter

}

public class APK implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private Long version;
    private String name;
    private Type type;

    //getter setter, toString, equals and hash code

}
```

Getting the below error with this code:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering
>   com.domain.data.B from com.domain.data.A has the wrong number of
>   column. should be 5

Please Help on this.

Comment: If you only need to know the `id` of A to usinquely identify the A that is referred to by B, then why are name and version part of the entity Id? Why do you use such horrible composite keys when you could use a single field as ID?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by using below mapping

```
@Table(name = "A")
@IdClass(APK.class)
public class A {



@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="a")
    private List<B> b; 
//getter and setter for b

}

@Table(name = "B")
@IdClass(BPK.class)
public class B {



@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
      @JoinColumn(name = "name", insertable = false, updatable = false),
      @JoinColumn(name = "version", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
private A a;

//getter and setter for a

}
```

The JPQL query is "select i from B i INNER JOIN i.a n WHERE n.id=:id"

Comment: I am getting null value for the query. If I pass the result as a list ,it should display 7 row of records but it gives 7 times as null. Any suggestions?